# No sound after TBOPlayer install on Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio

I found omxplayer to be a bit slow to use if you need to add a song manually every time, so I installed a GUI: TBOPlayer.

This GUI works perfectly, you can add folders of music etc. and it even has a YouTube search that will go find a YT video to display it as well as the sound going with it.

On the other hand, since I installed it, all other sounds are not working as expected. For example, going directly on YouTube from Chromium to watch a video will only give me video, but no sound.

The output is currently the jack, but it is the same on HDMI.

I do not really know where to look for a fix nor if it can be done so any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Drotciv

Answer (score 0):

Even HDMI port is used as video output, sometime, no sound.
Edit /boot/config.txt and remove # on line #hdmi_drive=2
Then record file and test.
Doesn't works if used on monitor using an adaptator DVI/HDMI.
Phil